# JQuery slider scrolling a div when dragging?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've got a basic slider and an overflow div that I offset based on the slider. To do this I use this;

```
slide: function(e, ui) {
            $("#myDiv").animate({left: ui.value * -1}, 500);
        },
        stop: function(e, ui) {
            $("#myDiv").animate({left: ui.value * -1}, 500);
        },
        change: function(e, ui) {
            $("#myDiv").css({left: ui.value * -1});
        }
```

This works great if I click somewhere on the slider or use the mouse wheel/arrow keys. However, if I drag the slider left and right and drop it somewhere, the div keeps doing it's scrolling thing, jumping back and forth. It doesn't really 'snap' once i release the mouse.

Is there some cleaner way to do this so that it does in fact track?

Comment: detach your code in 'slide' event... i think 'stop' and 'change' will do your animation perfectly

Comment: That almost works, no more odd behavior, but the div no longer scrolls until i release the slider.. So as I'm dragging it, the div is static. When I drop, it catches up. I'd like this to act more like an actual scrollbar and slide the div as it moves..

Comment: well simple way to do that is remove animation/delay(500) in 'slide' event... just re-arrange the div to appropriate position... it'll look like animation

Answer (score 0):

just modifying your code

```
slide: function(e, ui) {
        // here replace the delay / remove animation and place div in exact position
        $("#myDiv").animate({left: ui.value * -1}, 0);
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        $("#myDiv").animate({left: ui.value * -1}, 500);
    },
    change: function(e, ui) {
        $("#myDiv").css({left: ui.value * -1});
    }
```

Comment: This is what I tried -- if you set slider's animate property to true and click at say 80% when its at 10%, the slider animates, but the div jumps. If I change it to animate,500 on the slide call, the weird behavior returns..